# Query on Azure Monitor Alert Frequency of evaluation

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-monitoring

In Azure monitor, I like to setup an alert for a SQL DB with Frequency of evaluation once every 12 hrs but max limit available is only 1 hour. Is there any other way to achieve this requirement..

Tried max limit of 1 hour and it is not editable.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, azure doesn't provide this integration in monitor to connect directly to SQL. Instead, I created a logic app or MS Flow to execute my SQL and generate the alert from there if possible. Else, create an event into application insight and run azure monitor for that activity log event.